# Why ResultSet returning 0 value after execution?

Tags: java, mysql

i guess i'm too tired or what.. Can't see anything bad here.

```
        String select = "SELECT project_id FROM project WHERE project_key = ?";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 = con.prepareStatement(select);
    preparedStatement1.setString(1, project_key);
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement1.executeQuery();

    int project_id = 0;

    while(rs.next()) {
            project_id = rs.getInt("project_id");
    }
    System.out.println(project_id);
```

the problem is why project_id returning me 0?

P.S. In database, i do have my project table fully inserted, and yes, i double checked value that are asked.

Comment: The last record to be processed in the loop has a `project_id` value of zero.

Comment: Why are you doing setString? Usually keys are Integers. setInt would be more apropriate.

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger built into your IDE. Reaching for the debugger is the **first** thing to do, not the last thing to do. Whereas posting on SO is near the end of the list. BTW, `while` is the wrong control structure there. It works, but it's the wrong structure for retrieving values from a **single** row. `if` is the correct structure when dealing with a single row.

Comment: Make sure your while loop been executed.

Comment: or the first call to `rs.next()` returns `false` or the last call to `rs.getInt("project_id");` returns `0`

Comment: For my project it will be random string.. @Tschallacka

Comment: @atiqkhaled loop is not being executed, don't know why..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i was debugging, saw that while loop is not executed.

Comment: @Ervinas34: Great! Now you know there is no match. The next step is...more debugging, to find out *why* there was no match. Other than the `while` (which is workable as-is) and perhaps some error handling being missing, the code is fine.

Comment: Do you see that the loop is going to keep overwriting `project_id`?

Comment: @Ervinas34 Can you show your DB?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen changed while to if statement, moreover i want it to return the ID from database table.

Comment: your while loop not been executed thats why its print intialise project_id 0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following code to see if the result set returns any value

```
rs.first();
System.out.println(rs.getInt("project_id"));
```

If you don't see any value it means that the problem has to do with the query. Nothing is returned and the set is empty.
(I was going to comment this but I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: why did this answer got downvoted twice while it is the accepted answer?

Comment: I'd not downvoted, but It can be considered wrong. because It can throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to be

```
while(rs.next()) {
       int project_id = rs.getInt("project_id");
        System.out.println(project_id);
}
```

I guess you will see no values (if there is a problem with the project_key)

Or many values the last one will be zero!